# Power Automate Regex expression

Tags: expression, extract, power-automate, power-platform

I need a Power Automate expression to extract a substring from a string, based on the regex

```
AA-BBB-\d{1,6}
```

but apparently Power Automate doesn't offer a regex match/extract function via expressions. Is there an easy way, possibly a short custom expression?

Comment: Correct, no regex at present, you can do it via this though ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/advanceddataoperatio/#regex-matches ... sign up for a trial here ... https://www.statesolutions.com.au/pricing ... you'll need a premium licence though.

Comment: Skin already provided you with a nice option. Alternative options could also be a Custom connector: https://github.com/mattybeard/PowerAutomate_CustomConnectors/tree/master/RegexReplace or even an Office script: https://www.tachytelic.net/2021/04/power-automate-regex/

Answer (score 0):

You can use RegEx in Power Automate without using any custom connector using

> Excel Run script action
> and create RegEx function in any Excel using office script typescript language. It's simple straightforward not much complex to do.

Full detailed implementation can be checked on this link.

[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S22719J_yXw]